# Are games bought on PlayStation Plus discount still available to play after the subscription expires?

Tags: psn, playstation-plus

I got a new PS4. It comes with 2 weeks of PS+. If I activate it and use discounts that are available (like DriveClub), will those be available to play after the "trial PS+" expires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you buy a game that has a PS Plus discount, you will still have access to that game when your subscription expires. This is different from redeeming an "Instant Game Collection" title, that you lose access to.

Answer (score 0):

TZHX is right. However, if you renew your subscription, you will be able to play those games you lost access due expiration of PS Plus again.

Comment: This is not always true. Sony has warned that you only regain access to games that are still available for licensing. In order to reactivate games from an expired subscription, you must re-download them. If the game is no longer on Sony's servers then you can not re-download it, this is why it's better to never let the subscription laps if you can help it.